# Convert a pandas dataframe from rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas

Updating to get the correct answer:
My data frame is in the format. Below is just the dummy data

```
A         B
'Animal'  'Tiger'
'Speed'   '1'
'Mammal'  'Yes'
'Animal'  'Elephant'
'Speed'   '10'
'Mammal'  'No'
'Animal'  'Leapord'
'Speed'   '30'
'Mammal'  'No'
```

Desired output

```
Animal   Speed Mammal
Tiger    1     Yes
Elephant 10    Yes
Leapord  30    yes
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check question no.10

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this like so:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['col1','col2','col3'], 'B': ['val1', 'val2','val3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index("A")
df = df.T
print(df.head)
```

Output:

```
A  col1  col2  col3
B  val1  val2  val3
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. However this is not what I want exactly. I have updated the description of my question, to reflect accurately what I am looking for. Thanks for your help though.